# Adding an item to an InfoPath 2010 form's repeating table using SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, infopath2010

I need to update an infopath form and add an item into a repeating table when an item is added to another list using SPD 2010 work flow.
Scenario:

- I have two forms libraries "FL1" and "FL2"
  when i create or update an item in FL1 i need to edit an item in FL2 to add an item to its repeating table.
- I already created a workflow which creates a from in FL2 when a form is added to FL1

Please let me know how to do this and what is the best method to complete it.